# Selfhosted Nancy: NullReferenceException occurred in Nancy.Authentication.Forms.dll When correct user/password is entered

Tags: c#, nancy

I am trying to create a form auth with self hosted Nancy.To make it simple there is no db for user data, it is stored in a List.We have two users:

U: admin P: passowrd

U: user P: password

I am using:

```
Nancy.1.4.4
Nancy.Authentication.Forms.1.4.1
Nancy.Hosting.Self.1.4.1
Nancy.Viewengines.Razor.1.4.3
Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.2.0.30506.0
```

My login module:

```
Get["/login"] = x =>
            {
                Model.login = new LoginModel() { Error = this.Request.Query.error.HasValue, ReturnUrl = this.Request.Url };
                return View["login", Model];
            };

            Post["/login"] = x =>
            {
                var userGuid = MyUserMapper.ValidateUser((string) this.Request.Form.Username,
                    (string) this.Request.Form.Password);

                if (userGuid == null)
                {
                    return Context.GetRedirect("~/login?error=true&username=" +
                                               (string) this.Request.Form.Username);
                }

                DateTime? expiry = null;
                if (this.Request.Form.RememberMe.HasValue)
                {
                    expiry = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
                }


                return this.LoginAndRedirect(userGuid.Value, expiry);
```

When a wrong user/password is entered everything is ok.When a correct user/password is entered NullReferenceException occurs at LoginAndRedirect:

```
return this.LoginAndRedirect(userGuid.Value, expiry);


An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Nancy.Authentication.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Call Stack:

```
>   NancyLinuxTest.exe!NancyLinuxTest.Models.MainModule..ctor.AnonymousMethod__16(dynamic x) Line 49    C#
```

Stack Trace:

```
Nancy.Authentication.Forms.FormsAuthentication.EncryptAndSignCookie(String cookieValue, FormsAuthenticationConfiguration configuration)\r\n   at Nancy.Authentication.Forms.FormsAuthentication.BuildCookie(Guid userIdentifier, Nullable`1 cookieExpiry, FormsAuthenticationConfiguration configuration)\r\n   at Nancy.Authentication.Forms.FormsAuthentication.UserLoggedInRedirectResponse(NancyContext context, Guid userIdentifier, Nullable`1 cookieExpiry, String fallbackRedirectUrl)\r\n   at Nancy.Authentication.Forms.ModuleExtensions.LoginAndRedirect(INancyModule module, Guid userIdentifier, Nullable`1 cookieExpiry, String fallbackRedirectUrl)\r\n   at NancyLinuxTest.Models.MainModule.<.ctor>b__16(Object x) in d:\\prototype-prices\\for_delete\\#proto\\NancyFormAuthTest\\NancyFormAuthTest\\Modules\\MainModule.cs:line 55\r\n   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Func`2 , Object )\r\n   at Nancy.Routing.Route.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3(Object parameters, CancellationToken context)
```

userGuid.Value is not null.

[Full source here](https://github.com/BZ-CO/NancyFormAuthTest)

Comment: The NullReferenceException occurs inside a library and is therefore not a duplicate of the canonical NRE question.

Comment: Exact value of userGuid at that line is 55e1e49e-b7e8-4eea-8459-7a906ac4d4c0 .Thats the same Guid as in the User List. [Source](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/be4f8d42076e4e568a3742715437868e6c7d05af/src/Nancy.Authentication.Forms/ModuleExtensions.cs)

Comment: @mjwills that's a [Nancy extension method](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.Authentication.Forms/ModuleExtensions.cs). This is one of the reasons I hate the framework, debugging it is a hell. It throws NRE's and "Oops!"es all around, and the developer has claimed multiple times _"If you get errors, your code is complex. Simplify your code"_. That's not really a pragmatic approach to programming. The OP probably forgot to register or call something in the startup, and then the framework blows up at runtime.

Comment: NancyLinuxTest.exe!NancyLinuxTest.Models.MainModule..ctor.AnonymousMethod__16(dynamic x) Line 49 C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my problem, I was calling the wrong Bootstrapper :).

Answer (score 0):

```
private static string EncryptAndSignCookie(string cookieValue, FormsAuthenticationConfiguration configuration)
{
    var encryptedCookie = configuration.CryptographyConfiguration.EncryptionProvider.Encrypt(cookieValue);
    var hmacBytes = GenerateHmac(encryptedCookie, configuration);
    var hmacString = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacBytes);

    return String.Format("{1}{0}", encryptedCookie, hmacString);
}
```

The only line that can trigger NRE (in [v.1.4.1](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/v1.4.1/src/Nancy.Authentication.Forms/FormsAuthentication.cs#L329)) is the `configuration` deference. If you look in the code this is set by calling  [`Enable`](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/v1.4.1/src/Nancy.Authentication.Forms/FormsAuthentication.cs#L42). Start you investigation there, see when `Enable` is called, check what configuration gets passed in.

Disclaimer: I have no idea what Nancy is, nor do I care. This is basic code debugging *you* should be doing. Is all open source. Just step through it.